# Windows Server 2016 calculating dropped network packet percentage

Tags: networking, tcp, windows-server-2016

Running `netstat -s -p tcp` gives me output in this fashion

```
TCP Statistics for IPv4
      Active Opens                    = 
      Passive Opens                   =
      Failed Connection Attempts      = 
      Reset Connections               =
      Current Connections             = 
      Segments Received               =
      Segments Sent                   = 
      Segments Retransmitted          =
```

Now in order to calculate the number of dropped incoming packets, would I need to compute `Segments Retransmitted` / `Segments Received` ?

I've read online that it needs to be computed with `Segments Retransmitted` / `Segments Sent` but that seemed wrong. Link: [example 1](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-check-for-dropped-packets) [example 2](https://www.clouddirect.net/knowledge-base/KB0011163/checking-for-tcpip-packet-loss)

If this is not the correct way, how can I calculate or generate the percentage of dropped incoming packets?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot calculate the number of dropped incoming packets from that result.

If the packet is dropped, your system won't receive it. TCP works on an acknowledgement system. When one packet is received, the receiver sends an ACK. The sender then sends another one. If the packet is not received, then the receiving system doesn't know that anything's necessarily wrong but the sender does because the ACK has never come back, so it re-sends it.

What you can do, however, is calculate dropped outgoing packets. That would be "Segments Retransmitted / Segments Sent". The total segments sent includes all segments that were dropped. The segments retransmitted is all the segments that were re-sent as a result of the sending system (in this scenario, your system) not receiving an ACK from the TCP process and resending the packet until it got an ACK back or the connection failed.

To calculate dropped incoming packets, therefore, you would have to go on the sending system and calculate its dropped outgoing packets for that specific connection.

Comment: I understand, I guess what threw me off was comparing the output of `netstat` with `ifconfig` in linux. Ifconfig displays `RX dropped` and `TX dropped`. `RX` meaning receiving and `TX` meaning transmitted. Would you happen to know what it means when it says `RX dropped` ? It seems it is somehow calculating the dropped receiving packets.